# gdal 3.1 wants PROJ 6 symbols but my PROJ version is 7

Tags: r, gdal, proj

I'm trying to build gdal3.1 on my mac because brew only has version 2.4.4.6. I have PROJ 7.0.1 on my mac. When I run ./configure for gdal 3.1 it ends with the error: PROJ 6 symbols not found. What is needed to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by finding an old version of gcc from 2013. When I renamed that to gccOld, the ./configure process ran to completion. make still doesn't work but that's going to be a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

If it wants symbols, that means the build got past the compilation phase.  That implies you actually found the headers for Proj6.  I often have this issue on unix-like systems if there is a duplicate copy hidden somewhere from some other project.  If it needed proj-6, it should have simply died in the compilation from invalid method signatures.

Comment: Yeah, there are some files that have identical names scattered around my mac. I suspect they are not identical and then the issue is what order should the PATH have. Mine is currently `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin:/usr/local/git/bin`

Comment: `/opt/local/` is often where MacPorts puts stuff.  There is a good chance MacPorts auto installed Proj when it installed some other dependencies.

If gdal still uses the auto-conf builder, you can usually specify the proj install you want with --proj4=/<path>.  I probably screwed up the actual option but `./configure --help` should tell you what it is.